# Link ComboBox with Dictionary's values

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, combobox

I want to call 3 lists in a for loop with variables and get something like :

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
{
    Combobox MyList(i) = new Combobox();
    MyList(i).Width = 120;
    MyList(i).Height = 30;
    etc...
}
```

It can't be done this way, so I looked for some others ways and found that it could be done using a dictionary. But then I can't fill comboboxes with the values (that are lists) of my dictionary.

I did something like this:

```
namespace GenDet
{
    public partial class NewDetail : Page
    {
    int Nbe = 0;
    List<String> MyElements = new List<String>();
    List<String> MyElement1 = new List<String>();
    List<String> MyElement2 = new List<String>();
    List<String> MyElement3 = new List<String>();

    Dictionary<int, List<string>> MyDictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

    public NewDetail()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyDictionary.Add(1, MyElement1);
        MyDictionary.Add(2, MyElement2);
        MyDictionary.Add(3, MyElement3);
    }

    private void OnClick1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        string MyValue = MyList.SelectedValue.ToString();
        if (Nbe == 3)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Max elements reached", "Alert", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
        } else
        {
            AddList(Nbe, MyValue, MyElements);
        }

    }
    private void AddList (int Nbe, string MyValue, List<string> MyElements)
    {
        List<String> MyNewList = new List<String>();
        if (Nbe==0 || (MyElements[Nbe-1] != MyValue && (MyElements[Nbe-1] == "Mur" || MyValue == "Mur"))) 
        {
            //String MyListName = "MyNewList" + Nbe.ToString();
            MyElements.Add(MyValue);
            Nbe += 1;
        }
        for (int i = 1; i <= Nbe; i++)
        {
           //MyComboBox[i] = MyDictionary value for key = i;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it can be done the way you have first written but:

1.First create your comboBox array (`ComboBox[]`)

2.Indexing in C3 is with `[]` and not `()`

3.Indexes start at 0, so loop from 0 to 2

```
ComboBox[] MyList = new ComboBox[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    MyList[i] = new ComboBox();
    MyList[i].Width = 120;
    MyList[i].Height = 30;
    etc...
}
```

Comment: `Combobox MyList[i] = new Combobox()` is no valid Syntax.

Comment: @BoredomOverload of course not, thanks for mentioning, this is what happens when you copy and paste ;)